# Image style normalization to prevent overfitting

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

This is more of a scientific question and I am asking if anybody agrees to my concept:

Let's say we have images that have similar content but different styles, like night images of horses and day images of horses. We train a classification or something different on those images. But imagine that now we have to use that network for black and white images. It won't work too well.
This is a common problem of overfitting and we could prevent it by collecting more data, using transfer learning or other.

I would like to discuss another approach. Let's say we have a separate network that "normalizes" the style of different looking images, much like style transfer networks. But instead of combining images with paintings we find a new common style that all images should "normalize" to.

Now we train this network on the day and night images and get a common style representation which we can use to "normalize" the unseen black and white images. Hypothetically the network trained on the normalized dataset should work on the normalized new data.

Is that a possible (maybe too complicated) way to prevent overfitting.
I am not asking if it's practical but if it could work.